# What is the difference between seq and $ in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, forcing

I am unable to understand the difference between `seq`, which forces evaluation, and `$`, which also does the same.

Comment: What gave you the impression that `$` forces evaluation? It does no such thing. [`$!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36--33-) does force evaluation (and then applies a function to the forced value).

Comment: Also the type signature of thoe functions is quite different

Comment: If you are struggling with lazy evaluation and when something is evaluated, I recommend firing up ghci and playing with `:sprint` also i think simon marlowe has got an informative section about this in his book [parallel and concurrent programming in haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929)

Comment: `$` does not evaluate anything at all. It is in fact an operator that does not much more than altering the priority of how things bind in Haskell.

Comment: `$` is a normal function which you could define yourself: `($) = \f x -> f x; infixr 0 $`. There is nothing special about it; every instance of `$` can be replaced by function application with no effect on semantics. `seq` is a deeply magical primitive which establishes an evaluation order (it does not *force* evaluation - that isn't a meaningful concept in Haskell).

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq says: "`seq` is usually introduced to improve performance by avoiding unneeded laziness.  ---  

A note on evaluation order: the expression `seq a b` **does not guarantee that `a` will be evaluated before `b`**. The only guarantee given by `seq` is that both `a` and `b` will be evaluated before `seq` returns a value. In particular, this means that `b` may be evaluated before `a`."

Answer (score 3):

Haskell is lazily evaluated by default. So a "normal" function with `seq`'s signature (`a -> b -> b`) would ignore its first argument and then return its second - it couldn't do anything else with either argument because it doesn't know what they are!

But `seq` is a bit special and does something slightly different. Instead, it *strictly* evaluates its first argument and *then* returns its second argument. This is useful for a variety of purposes, such as forcing the order of side-effects, or for preventing large thunks from accumulating during a calculation. You can find out more info here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq.

As @palik said, the type signature of `$` is completely different, and it does something different: it applies a function to an argument. The difference between `$` and ordinary function application is that it has very low operator precedence, which lets you avoid writing a lot of parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` takes a function and a value. It returns a thunk. When that thunk is forced, it produces the result of applying the function to the value.

```
> let x = succ $ (2 :: Int)

> :sprint x
x = _

> x
3

> :sprint x
x = 3
```

`($)` is exactly equivalent to ordinary function application, but with lower operator precedence, which can be useful for avoiding some parentheses.

```
print (take 10 (map (* 2) (filter even [1..])))

print $ take 10 $ map (* 2) $ filter even [1..]
```

`seq :: a -> b -> b` is very different: it arranges a *dependency* between its result and its first argument, so that when the result is forced, the first argument is evaluated first:

```
> let y = succ (1 :: Int)

> :sprint y
y = _

> let z = y `seq` (3 :: Int)

> :sprint z
z = _

> z
3

> :sprint z
z = 3

> :sprint y
y = 2
```

Here, `y` and `z` are initially unevaluated thunks. But evaluating `z` has the side effect of also evaluating `y`, because we’ve arranged a dependency on `y` using `seq`. You can also observe the order of evaluation using `trace` from `Debug.Trace`:

```
> import Debug.Trace

> (trace "a evaluated" ()) `seq` (trace "b evaluated" ())
a evaluated
b evaluated
()

> let p = (trace "a evaluated" (1 :: Int), trace "b evaluated" (2 :: Int))

> :sprint p
p = (_,_)

> snd p
b evaluated
2

> :sprint p
p = (_,2)

> fst p
a evaluated
1

> :sprint p
p = (1,2)
```

`seq` is a low-level operation that’s mainly useful for performance reasons, because it lets you control when a thunk is evaluated. For example, `seq` is used in the definition of `foldl'` to ensure that the result of each step of the fold is evaluated before proceeding to the next step. Its lazy cousin `foldl` doesn’t do this, so it often accumulates a deeply nested series of thunks, which can result in a stack overflow when evaluated.

Comment: Thanks. But I am confused about: print $ take 10 $ map (* 2) $ filter even [1..]. If $ has low precedence, then why shouldn't it end up going to infinite loop, because it should evaluate filter even [1..] first, right?

Comment: @Programmer "lower precedence" refers to how an expression is *read*, or *parsed*. it means that the expression you've shown is read/parsed actually as `print (take 10 (map (* 2) (filter even [1..])))`. It is *not* about the evaluation order. That is determined by each of the named entities' *definitions*. The first is `print`, and it needs to know its argument, so `take 10` comes into play. *It* needs to know first 10 elements of *its* argument, `map (* 2) (filter even [1..])`, so `map (* 2)` comes into play, asking for the 10 first elements of `filter even [1..]` ... (not exactly,but approx)

Comment: @Programmer `seq` in `seq x y` (contrasted with `y`) can be seen as modifying the original *need* for `y` (if and when `y` is needed) to be saying "I additionally need `x` as well".

Answer (score 1):

`seq` and `($)` have different type signatures:

```
λ> :t seq
seq :: a -> b -> b
λ> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
λ> (+1) `seq` 2
2
λ> (+1) $ 2
3
```